# Group Footer - Bottom of page shows in the middle

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I have this Report in Crystal 2016.

We need to have the Group Footer to be on the bottom of the page.

- Group 1A, 1B (Keep Together)
- Group 1A, 1B (Print at Bottom of Page is selected)
- Group 1C (New Page Before is selected)

Group 1A & 1B are not on the bottom. Sometimes it shows in the middle of the page.
Group 1C works fine.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Underlay following section' on group 1A or 1B and see if that does anything.